# How to get groups in regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I want to print first, second and third matched group in an expression. Here is the details.

```
Regex Pattern = "(\d+)"
Expression = "1123-xxx-abcd-45-tsvt-35-pwrst-99-xql"
```

I used Pythex, https://pythex.org/?regex=(%5Cd%2B)&test_string=1123-xxx-abcd-45-tsvt-35-pwrst-99-xql&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0
It is working perfectly find and it displays all the captured groups.

But it is not working in python code. I provide below the python code, I am unable to find the problem.

```
import re


class Test3:

    def printAllGroups(self):
        regexPattern = r"(\d+)"
        text = "1123-xxx-abcd-45-tsvt-35-pwrst-99-xql"
        matcher = re.compile(regexPattern, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
        matchValue = matcher.match(text);
        if matchValue:
            print("First group : ", matchValue.group(1))
            print("Second group : ", matchValue.group(2))
            print("Third group : ", matchValue.group(2))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test3 = Test3()
    test3.printAllGroups()
```

Please help me solve this problem, I am new to Python.

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: [re.match()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match) checks for a match only at the beginning of the string.

Comment: If you want to capture all digits you must use findall instead of match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**code**:

```
import re

regexPattern = r"(\d+)"
expression = "1123-xxx-abcd-45-tsvt-35-pwrst-99-xql"
print(re.findall(regexPattern,expression))
```

**Output**:

```
['1123', '45', '35', '99']
```

In your current code you will have the error:

```
    print("Second group : ", matchValue.group(2))
IndexError: no such group
```

because there is only **one group** in the regex.

By changing your code in the following way, with the regex explained at 
https://regex101.com/r/BjTrgU/2, you will have one single match (the whole line) and four groups, that you can access individually, to extract the numbers.

It is important to distinguish the difference between a match (when your regex matches/verifies an input string) and a the value stores in the groups of your regex each defined by parenthesis `()`

1st occurrence of `()` in the regex will be accessible via backreference `\1` in the regex (or the replacement string) or `group(1)` outside of the regex, 2nd occurrence of `()` in the regex will be accessible via backerefence `\2` in the regex (or the replacement string) or `group(2)` outside of the regex,...

```
import re

class Test3:

    def printAllGroups(self):
        regexPattern = r"^(\d+)[^\d]+(\d+)[^\d]+(\d+)[^\d]+(\d+)[^\d]+$"
        text = "1123-xxx-abcd-45-tsvt-35-pwrst-99-xql"
        matcher = re.compile(regexPattern, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
        matchValue = matcher.match(text);
        if matchValue:
            print("First group : ", matchValue.group(1))
            print("Second group : ", matchValue.group(2))
            print("Third group : ", matchValue.group(3))
            print("Third group : ", matchValue.group(4))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test3 = Test3()
    test3.printAllGroups()
```

Output:

```
python test3.py
('First group : ', '1123')
('Second group : ', '45')
('Third group : ', '35')
('Third group : ', '99')
```

Comment: Really nice answer.